# Can't browse the file tree using letters in the latest version

Tags: visual-studio-code

In previous versions, I could type "mybot" for example while i'm in the explorer section and it would jump to the folder just like any file explorer.

In the latest version, i can't do that anymore, I have to do ctrl+f to find stuff.

This is so annoying, how do i reenable this?

Thanks!